# How do I place a UI button on image target using AR Camera and Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I want to place a UI button based on the image target. I am using Vuforia engine and I have an image which has chairs and tables. So I want to place a button on the UI (not a virtual button) based on image. For example, one button should be on the chair. When I move, the button should re-adjust to always show up over the chair and when clicked, it should display a 3d text saying that its a chair. I am a new to AR and wanted to explore onto some of such tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place UI elements in 3D space by choosing `WorldSpace` for the `RenderMode` a [`Canvas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas.html) (also see the [Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html)) via the inspector.

Than you can simply make that `Canvas` `GameObject` a child of the according ImageTarget. So that whenever the ImageTarget is moved (by the tracking) the `Canvas` is automatically moved along without having to take care of it.

Alternative you could also move and place the object with that `Canvas` attached like any other object in a component e.g.

```c#
public class PlaceCanvasOnTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform ImageTarget;
    public Canvas CanvasToPlace;

    // set an offset for the canvas e.g. 20cm above
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0.2, 0);

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Canvas.transform.position = ImageTarget.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Additionally afaik the childs of an ImageTarget by default get **not** all disabled onTrackingLost and enabled onTrackingFound. Only some components are disabled but you can change this by copying the content of `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` to a custom one and adjust it something like (important for you are only `OnTrackingFound` and `OnTrackingLost` at the bottom)

```c#
using UnityEngine;

namespace Vuforia
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.
    /// </summary>
    public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour,
    ITrackableEventHandler
    {
        #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

        private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

        #endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES


        #region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

        void Start()
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
            if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            {
                mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
            }
        }

        #endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS


        #region PUBLIC_METHODS
        public GameObject show;
        public GameObject hide;
        /// <summary>
        /// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
        /// tracking state changes.
        /// </summary>
        public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
            TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
            TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
        {
            if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
            {
                OnTrackingFound();
            }
            else
            {
                OnTrackingLost();
            }
        }

        #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS


        #region PRIVATE_METHODS

        private void OnTrackingFound()
        {
            show.SetActive(true);

            // enabled all children
            foreach(Transform child in transform)
            {
                child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
        }

        private void OnTrackingLost()
        {
            hide.SetActive(true);

            // disable all children
            foreach(Transform child in transform)
            {
                child.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
        }

        #endregion // PRIVATE_METHODS
    }
}
```

---

For the button showing and hiding some text:

1. Add a `Button` as child to the `Canvas`.
2. Add a `Panel` as child to the `Canvas`. And add a `Text` as child to that `Panel`. (You don't need to use a Panel - it is basically just an `Image` component - but it might be easier to read the Text if it placed on a semitransparent or opaque surface instead of just "floating" in the air)
3. Than make a simple component

   ```c#
   public TogglePanel : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public void Toggle()
       {
           gameObject.SetActive(!gameObject.activeSelf);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Attach that component to the `Panel` object
5. In the `Button`'s `onClick` event now reference the `TogglePanel` component and select the method `TogglePanel`->`Toggle()`

---

The result should be now

- OnTracking lost: Canvas (Button and Panel with Text) disapears
- OnTracking found: Canvas (Button and evtl Panel with Text) appears and should always be on top of the chair (imageTarget);
- OnButtonClick: Panel with Text should get enabled or disabled